How does LazyColumn/LazyRow extract each composables from items block
I am implementing my own custom layout.

So there is a centre Node. As of getting branch nodes(in parameter of composable) i thought of using item block as we regularly use in lazylist composables. When i saw the implemention of lazylists, it was complicated and i couldn't understand it. If i were to do this
    val branchNodes = @Composable {
        repeat(nodes) { index -> branchNode(index) }
    }


It gives a box of composable one below another.
If items block isn't the best approach, what should i do?

I'm not sure I undestand what you are asking. Can you describe it more detail what you try to achieve and what problems you are facing?

@Leviathan As u can see in the image, that is the type of composable i am trying to achieve by creating my custom composable, the circle on middle is called centreNode while other are refered as branchNodes. This is my composable
@Composable
fun Connector(
 modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
 nodes: Int,
 centre: @Composable () -> Unit,
 branchNode: @Composable (index: Int) -> Unit, // As of this how to receive all of those
)

what way should i use to get all those branchNode composables. One way is how lazyLists do it, through item block(check the link in original question).

@androidDeweleper I think your question actually is not about LazyColumn or items. It's rather about how to create a graph Composable which dynamically positions the child nodes.

@androidDeweleper I don't think LazyColumn is the best choice for your use case. I would suggest using Canvas instead. This way, you can also connect the nodes as shown in the image. https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/graphics/draw/overview
